# Como fazer uma consulta com Node.js e MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Olá, estou começando com `Node.js` e `MySQL`, e tenho alguns problemas no momento. Bem, tenho uma tabela chamada usuarios, e preciso fazer a requisição de dados para verificação, por exemplo: O meu site possui um formulário de cadastro, mas precisa verificar os dados para ver se não há um usuário já cadastrado com os mesmos dados.

O meu código está assim até agora:

```
 var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database:'tabela'
});

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  // Use the connection
  var email = emailCadastro;
  connection.query( 'SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = ?',[email], function(err, rows) {
    // And done with the connection.
    connection.release();

    // Don't use the connection here, it has been returned to the pool.
    console.log(rows[0].email);
  });
});
```

Por favor me corrijam se este código estiver errado. A variável `emailCadastro` vem do form do usuário.

O interpretador retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
```

Gostaria de saber qual é o erro aqui e se alguem poderia me ajudar.

Comment: A sua base de dados se chama mesmo "tabela"?

Comment: Não. Por que? Isso nao afeta a pergunta certo?

Comment: Depende, se o problema for uma base que não existe, afeta.

Comment: Bem a tabela existe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguindo a [documentação do node-mysql esse método só aceita 2 argumentos](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/#introduction). A query e a callback.

Se o que precisas é de passar o email para a query então deves concatenar isso com `+` que é o simbolo de concatenação em JavaScript. Sugiro mudares o código como coloco em baixo (eventualmente podes ter de tirar as aspas à volta dessa string com o mail):

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  // Use the connection
  var email = emailCadastro;
  connection.query( 'SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email="' + email + '"', function(err, rows) {
```

Comment: ainda retorna "undefined"

Comment: @Perrytheplatypus o que dá console.log(email) antes da `connection`?

Comment: undefined . Acho que nao esta pegando os dados do form. vou verificar

Comment: acho que o problema está no loop de dados, que nao estou conseguindo realizar. No php por exemplo usa-se um while e mysql_fetch_array, qual seria essa função em node mysql?

Comment: @Perrytheplatypus em node a callback dá todos os resultados de uma vez só. Se precisares de iterar podes fazer `.forEach`. Mas se o email dá undefined tens de adicionar o código de onde vais buscar `emailCadastro` para ver o que se passa aí.

Comment: obrigado, era isso mesmo